# How to remove a specific column from a file using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Hello everyone I am working with a text that looks as follows:

```
& & Training &  &  &   & Early birds &  &   &  &  & Test &   \\\hline
& EN & ES & IT & DU &  EN & ES & IT & DU  & EN & ES & IT & DU  \\\hline
Users & 152 & 110 & 38   & 34& 42 & 30 & 12 & 10 & 142 & 88 & 36 & 32 \\\hline
18-24  & 58 & 22 &  & & 16 & 6 &  & & 56 & 18 & & \\
25-34  & 60 & 56 &  & &16 & 14 & &  & 58 & 44 & &\\
35-49   & 22   & 22  &  &  & 6& 6 & &  & 20 & 18 & &\\
50+  & 12 & 10 &  & & 4& 4 & &  & 8 &8 &  & \\\hline
```

I am using the & symbol as a column separator, I would like to remove the seven column of my text.txt using awk, I tried:

```
awk -F "&" '{print $7}' text.txt
```

and I get:

```
Early birds
 ES
 30
 6
 14
 6
 4
```

which is the column that I want to remove from my text.txt, I would like to achieve this using awk, I would like to appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` works well for this:

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^&]*&){6})[^&]*&/\1/' text.txt
& & Training &  &  &   &  &   &  &  & Test &   \\\hline
& EN & ES & IT & DU &  EN & IT & DU  & EN & ES & IT & DU  \\\hline
Users & 152 & 110 & 38   & 34& 42 & 12 & 10 & 142 & 88 & 36 & 32 \\\hline
18-24  & 58 & 22 &  & & 16 &  & & 56 & 18 & & \\
25-34  & 60 & 56 &  & &16 & &  & 58 & 44 & &\\
35-49   & 22   & 22  &  &  & 6& &  & 20 & 18 & &\\
50+  & 12 & 10 &  & & 4& &  & 8 &8 &  & \\\hline
```

`(([^&]*&){6})` matches the first six columns and saves them in group `\1`. `[^&]*&` matches the seventh.  All of that gets replaced with just the first six columns, `\1`.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help, `sed`  achieves what I want, very well.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(([^&]*&){6})[^&]*&/,"\\1",1)}' file
& & Training &  &  &   &  &   &  &  & Test &   \\\hline
& EN & ES & IT & DU &  EN & IT & DU  & EN & ES & IT & DU  \\\hline
Users & 152 & 110 & 38   & 34& 42 & 12 & 10 & 142 & 88 & 36 & 32 \\\hline
18-24  & 58 & 22 &  & & 16 &  & & 56 & 18 & & \\
25-34  & 60 & 56 &  & &16 & &  & 58 & 44 & &\\
35-49   & 22   & 22  &  &  & 6& &  & 20 & 18 & &\\
50+  & 12 & 10 &  & & 4& &  & 8 &8 &  & \\\hline
```

With other awks it's a bit more work:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^&]*&){7}/) { tgt=substr($0,1,RLENGTH); sub(/[^&]*&$/,"",tgt); $0=tgt substr($0,RLENGTH+1) } 1' file
& & Training &  &  &   &  &   &  &  & Test &   \\\hline
& EN & ES & IT & DU &  EN & IT & DU  & EN & ES & IT & DU  \\\hline
Users & 152 & 110 & 38   & 34& 42 & 12 & 10 & 142 & 88 & 36 & 32 \\\hline
18-24  & 58 & 22 &  & & 16 &  & & 56 & 18 & & \\
25-34  & 60 & 56 &  & &16 & &  & 58 & 44 & &\\
35-49   & 22   & 22  &  &  & 6& &  & 20 & 18 & &\\
50+  & 12 & 10 &  & & 4& &  & 8 &8 &  & \\\hline
```

or since you have a string FS rather than a regexp:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="&"} { j=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i!=7) printf "%s%s",(++j>1?OFS:""),$i; print "" }' file
& & Training &  &  &   &  &   &  &  & Test &   \\\hline
& EN & ES & IT & DU &  EN & IT & DU  & EN & ES & IT & DU  \\\hline
Users & 152 & 110 & 38   & 34& 42 & 12 & 10 & 142 & 88 & 36 & 32 \\\hline
18-24  & 58 & 22 &  & & 16 &  & & 56 & 18 & & \\
25-34  & 60 & 56 &  & &16 & &  & 58 & 44 & &\\
35-49   & 22   & 22  &  &  & 6& &  & 20 & 18 & &\\
50+  & 12 & 10 &  & & 4& &  & 8 &8 &  & \\\hline
```